# I am making a simple program using interpolation search in c++. I am wondering why it would not read the elements I input in the array

Tags: c++, arrays, interpolation

```
int interpolationSearch(int arr[], int n, int x)
{
int lo = 0, hi = (n - 1);
while (lo <= hi && x >= arr[lo] && x <= arr[hi])
{
    if (lo == hi)
    {
        if (arr[lo] == x) return lo;
        return -1;
    }

    int pos = lo + (((double)(hi - lo) / (arr[hi] - arr[lo])) * (x - arr[lo]));
    if (arr[pos] == x )
        return pos;
    if (arr[pos < x])
        lo = pos + 1;
    else
        hi = pos - 1;
}
return -1;
}

    int main ()
   {
int arr[10], x;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter a value: ";
    cin >> arr[i];
}
cout << "\nEnter a value to search: ";
cin >> x;
int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

int index = interpolationSearch(arr, n, x);
if (index != -1)
    cout << "found at index " << index;
else
    cout << "not found.";
return 0;
}
```

Here is my code. Perhaps my formula is wrong or something? I don't know but when I input sorted numbers in the array and search for a particular number, it won't return anything.

Comment: Look at `if (arr[pos < x])` until you spot the bug.

Comment: Interesting... The algorithm works only for sorted arrays, and in case there are repeated values inside the array, the algorithm won't necessarily yield the first position.